# IIS 6.0: mutliple SSL host headers assigned to same site

Tags: iis, ssl

Can I bind two different hostnames (one.example.com , two.example.com) to a single secure site in IIS?

I have a wildcard certificate (self signed)  *.example.com and I've used the adsutil tool to add
the following SecureBindings

":443:one.example.com" ":443:two.example.com"

I've run the Microsoft SSLDiagnostics tool and it shows me the following message

"Site A and A have conflicting SecureBindings"

(where A is the id of my site).

when I try open the site IE tells me it cannot display the page, Firefox tells me connection interrupted while loading (when I use either of the hostnames)

I actually already have several sites using the same wildcard and have applied the ssl bindings to those using Adsutil, that works a treat each site gets a single ssl host binding.
This question is more specifically around a new scenario where I have two DNS entries which should both go to the same site.

Answer (score 0):

If one.example.com and two.example.com are the only two sites you want to run on that IP address with SSL there is no need to specify the host headers. Just let the DNS entries for both point to that IP address and it will work.

If however, you also want to run a three.example.com with SSL on the same server, on a different IP address, using the same wildcard SSL certificate, you can do it. By default IIS manager will not allow you to specify a hostname in the bindings dialog if you choose HTTPS. However, there is a neat trick that will enable this and that is to rename the friendly name of your SSL certificate to *.example.com. This can be done in the certificate manager. IIS guru Scott Forsyth has a [nice video that explains this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=HPiG98p-RDc).

Comment: Updated question

Comment: So it's only the site with more than one hostname that gives you problems?  If you remove the extra hostnames and just have one it works?